# Spring: Using @Qualifier & @Profile

Tags: java, spring

I have a component class (let's class in `MyService`) which is marked by `@Qualifier(US)`.

As this component needed some values present in an `application.yml` file, I also marked the class with `@Profile({"default", "qual"})` to get the correct values for some inner properties of the class.

Problem, when I execute cucumber tests for this specific qualifier (US), the program throws the following error `An unexpected internal server error occurred: No bean named 'US' available: No matching MyService bean found for qualifier 'US' - neither qualifier match nor bean name match!`

So, what I understand with this, it's the annotations `@Qualifier` & `@Profile` don't work together. Is that right? Or do I miss something to use both of them in the same class?

Comment: Profile isn't for fetching values - it's for specifying parts of your app that are to be deployed in certain condition. Your error means you run your tests with different profiles, so your qualified bean isn't deployed to application context.

Comment: If the profile attribute of the beans element is supplied e.g., <beans profile="p1,p2">, the beans element will not be parsed unless at least profile 'p1' or 'p2' has been activated. Likewise, if a `@Component` or `@Configuration` class is marked with @Profile({"p1", "p2"}), that class will not be registered or processed unless at least profile 'p1' or 'p2' has been activated.-*from spring docs*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@Qualifer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html)

> This annotation may be used on a field or parameter as a qualifier for
>   candidate beans when autowiring.

[@Profile](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html)

> Indicates that a component is eligible for registration when one or
>   more specified profiles are active.

The class with following set of annotations

```
@Service
@Qualifier("US")
@Profile({"default", "qual"})
public class MyService {
...}
```

will only register the MyService bean when "default" or "qual" profiles are active and then on the bean can be autowired with the qualifier "US"

```
@Autowired
@Qualifer("US")
private MyService myService;
```

[@Value](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) can be used to inject the properties

```
@Value(${some.name})
private String name;
```